# How to speed-up Envoy proxy bazel build?

Tags: bazel, envoyproxy

I build Envoy Proxy from scratch in the CI Docker image like following

```
./ci/run_envoy_docker.sh './ci/do_ci.sh dev'
```

Although the "dev" target turns on the "fastbuild" option, it still takes an extremely long time to build the envoy binary. The use of a remote_cache has brought a significant improvement in the compilation of individual actions

```
./ci/run_envoy_docker.sh \"BAZEL_BUILD_OPTIONS='--remote_cache=http://cachesrv:8000' ./ci/do_ci.sh dev
```

Nevertheless, the entire run of bazel (startup, dependency checks, linking, etc) takes still long time when changing single source files.

How can the response time of the Envoy bazel build be further increased in order to develop a filter iteratively?